# Excel report open insted of downloading on Firefox JBOSS server

Tags: firefox, jboss, download, struts-1

When click on the Excel download Firefox opens the Excel in new tab instead of downloading, but Chrome  downloads it normally. This program is run on JBOSS server. This developed using sturts 1 and java EE. Want a solution for this. Download Excel in Firefox browser too.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  Can you show your code please? please also have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It depends on browser configuration. You cannot control your clients browsers.

Comment: Hi. I can't publish a code because it's proprietary. I just want to know is it possible with jboss server. @BrianTompsett